# How do you say "in the table"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, preposiciones

- "In the cupboard" → "En la despensa"
- "On the cupboard" → "Encima de la despensa"
- "On the table" → "En la mesa"
- "In the table" → "???"

Esto no es una mesa con la despensa. La superficie de la mesa se abre. Esto es mi la mesa arquetipo. Se abre.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! It is an interesting question, as tables do not usually open, and sentences like "dentro de la mesa" sound strange to me (but can be perfectly valid). Nonetheless, I am afraid that I have not understood your last sentences. Do not be afraid of asking in English if you are still not comfortable with Spanish. Does the table just open and extend itself? Or does it have drawers in it?

Comment: The table surface opens, kind of like a trap door, revealing a storage space.

Comment: It is funny because tables usually do not have an "inside", but in your case angus's answer seems the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de la mesa.

> [**dentro**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=dentro) *adv*
>
> 1. inside
> 2. **dentro de**
>    2.1 (=*en el interior de*) in, inside
>    2.2 (= *después de*) in
>    2.3 (= *en los límites de*) within
>
> <sup>Collins Spanish Dictionary - Complete and Unabridged - 8th Edition 2005 © HarperCollins Publishers</sup>

Variant: Adentro de la mesa.

Answer (score 1):

*En la mesa* is a good translation for both *On the table* and *In the table*

In English you can be very specific about where are the things placed. In contrast, Spanish can be very ambiguous and you'll need to say more in order to be more specific.

*Dentro de la mesa* is a good interpretation but if something is inside the table I'd rather say **En el cajon de la mesa** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would translate myself as "Sobre la mesa". Even though the correct English form would be "Over the table". Spanish is not specific all the time when referring to the positioning of objects and we often don't use "in" in the same way as it is used in English. We could say "dentro de la mesa" but that does not really make much sense unless we specify that it is in a cupboard or the table can be opened somehow.

Comment: I have trouble finding another meaning for "La superficie de la mesa abrir" besides the table surface moves/opens.